# How can I create assembly reference for mscorlib.dll ver 5 in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, clr, sql-server-2012

I Use SQL Server 2012 and I want create CLR

I want execute this command in SQL Server 2012

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY AndishCSSCommon FROM 'C:\Andish.CSS.Common.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET=EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

But I get this error

```
Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Assembly 'Andish.CSS.Common' references assembly 'mscorlib, version=5.0.5.0,  
 culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e.', which is not present in the current
 database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced 
assembly     from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that     operation 
has failed     (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the 
referenced     assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

and in my debug folder not exist mscorlib.dll

how can I `CREATE ASSEMBLY` for `mscorlib.dll` before `CREATE ASSEMBLY AndishCSSCommon FROM 'C:\Andish.CSS.Common.dll'`

Comment: There isn't a 5.0.5.0 version of `mscorlib` in the standard framework. Some googling suggests there may be one in Silverlight - so it sounds like you might be trying to use an assembly that depends on Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the target framework to a more recent one from your project's

> Properties -> Application -> Target framework.